# Regular expression for Indian landline Phone numbers

Tags: python, regex

Indian landline phone numbers are in one of the following format.

```
080 25478965
0416-2565478
08172-268032
```

Whats the simplest Regex to accommodate all these. The space between the city code and the phone number can be a whitespace or a "-". It would be great if the regex can accommodate the case without the separator between the city code and the phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably just use `/^(\d+[ \-]+\d+)$/` if you don't need to verify the number of digits etc. If you'd like to get both parts separated: `/^(\d+)[ \-]+(\d+)$/`

Comment: That would be my approach too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For these three formats exactly:

```
^\d{3}([ -]\d\d|\d[ -]\d|\d\d[ -])\d{6}$
```

Another, more liberal option, is to allow a space or a dash after each digit (except maybe the last):

```
^(\d[ -]?){10}\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\d]{3,4}[\-\s]*[\d]{6,7}$
```

This would match [3-4 digits][zero to many dashes and whitespaces][6-7 digits]